# Retrieve Info From Callback Thread Safe Implementation

Tags: c, multithreading, callback, pthreads

I am getting data from a callback function e.g.

```
static char *buf;

int cb(char *c) {
    // append to global var buf
    append(buf, c);
    return 0;
}

int foo() {
    ...
    bar(cb); // calls cb
    ...
}
```

As is evident I append the info from each time the callback is called to a global var(`buf`) as I cannot pass anything else in. Now the problem is that I need to make this thread safe with POSIX threads. How can I safely retrieve the information? Note: I cannot change the type of `cb` which must be `int (*cb)(char *c)`.

Comment: What 'information' do you want to 'retrieve safely'? Isn't putting a lock around `append(buf, c);` all you need? I'm confused.

Comment: @meaning-matters Won't having multiple threads all overwrite `buf` and the lock only prevent it happening it at the same time? Obviously this is not actually the real code but basically the information can be retrieved from `c` in `cb`

Comment: Yes, all threads would overwrite `buf`. I now understand better what you want; have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4118943/1971013). It would be good to give a broader view of your design, instead of zooming in to what seems to be the issue; there might be different ways.

Comment: @meaning-matters All of the answers basically say there are better ways than use these global workarounds. I was wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: People might be able to suggest a 'better way' if you'd show a broader view of you design, as I suggested yesterday.

Comment: @meaning-matters The design must have the callback as its forced by a library and information is collected from that callback. Sorry I can't share more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a C module that manages your buffers; one per thread.  In this way you get rid of the global variable(s).

In this module you need a data-structure that uniquely maps a thread-ID to its buffer.  You could use a hash-table.  (But, if your platform's thread-IDs are 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., you could use a dynamically [re-]allocated array with thread-ID as index; of course if your application does not start massive amounts of threads.)

You then need a function like `char* getBuffer()` that does the lookup.  You could have a `createBuffer()` which you call when `getBuffer()` returns `NULL`.  You'd need logic to clean up buffers, ...; you'll get the idea.

Make sure that the functions that modify this internal data-structure are thread-safe.